# Can I use nicefrac within siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, nicefrac

I suspect the answer is a straight 'No', but nothing ventured... I have a table of time periods (minutes and hours), and a couple of the periods involve the fraction 1/2. I generally use the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package for numbers and units, as it gives a nice spacing between the number and the unit. I could use 0.5 rather than the fraction 1/2, but in this particular case the fraction is more aesthetically and stylistically pleasing. I have tried using the `\nicefrac{1}{2}` macro within the first brackets of the `\SI{*number*}{*unit*}` macro, but it does not seem to work. Is there another way of achieving the same objective?

MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
A nice fraction: 2\nicefrac{1}{2}.

Some time periods:

\SI{1}{\minute}

\SI{5}{\minute}

\SI{2}{\hour}

The above all works fine.

% This, however, does not:

% \SI{2\nicefrac{1}{2}}{\minute}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\SI[fraction-function=\nicefrac,quotient-mode = fraction]{1/2}{\minute}` would work if the num is only a quotient. But I have no idea how to add the "2" before it. Addition: Well `\SI[fraction-function=\nicefrac,quotient-mode = fraction,product-units = single,output-product={\,}]{2x1/5}{\minute}` seems to work.

Comment: But 2x1/5 is naturally mathematically dubious ...

Comment: Your solution also works perfectly @Ulrike_Fischer, but I've gone with Joseph's because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For cases where you want to do things beyond the understanding of the `siunitx` internals, you can turn the parser off

```
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{2\nicefrac{1}{2}}{\minute}
```

Answer (score 4):

The option `fraction-function=\nicefrac` option will do just that, but you'll need to load the package `nicefrac` and set `quotient-mode = fraction` as well.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    quotient-mode = fraction,
    fraction-function=\nicefrac
}

\begin{document}
    \nicefrac{1}{3} \num{1/3}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This works well for numbers.  I tried it with `\si{\kilogram / \square \meter}`, which gives different results :-(